# Having some trouble making a simple ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, webmethod

I started switching things over to `[WebMethod]`s but started having trouble and decided I needed to do some more research on how to use them properly.

I put the following in `$(document).ready()`

```
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: "{}",
                url: "http://localhost:3859/Default.aspx/ajxTest",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg, status) {
                    alert(msg.name + " " + msg.value);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var somethingDarkside; //only to put a breakpoint in.
                    alert(xhr.statusText);

                }
            });
```

My `[WebMethod]`

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string ajxTest()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        DummyString dum = new DummyString("Please","Work");
        string jsonString = ser.Serialize(dum);
        return jsonString;
    }
```

I never get "Please work". I get "undefined undefined" I'm able to debug in VS and the call enters the `[WebMethod]`, the return string looks correct for JSON but I haven't been able to get a successful call out of it yet. I've got parse errors, transport errors. Everything is inconsistent but nothing has ever been right. I've had up to 47 different blogs, SO posts and google group tabs up today, I can't quite crack it.

The `xhr.statusText` status is OK as posted. I am getting a `status` parse error. I'm lost.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: jQuery 1.9.1

EDIT2: DummyString object

```
        public class DummyString
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }

        public DummyString(string n, string v)
        {
            name = n;
            value = v;
        }
    }
```

EDIT 3: Also I have `<asp:ScriptManager EnablePageMethods="true" ...`

Comment: What exactly _are_ the contents of your result string?

Comment: Have you ever debugged it in browser?

Comment: The browser debug is how I got the `status` parse error.

`DummyString` works like a dictionary. It returns a `name:please, value:work` thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/ajxTest",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('fail');
    }
});
```

and

```
[WebMethod]
public static string ajxTest()
{
    return @"{ ""hello"":""hola"" }";
}
```

and test. (the above will work)

Comment: I get a fail from this. This is where I started too, trying the most simple way. I'm having a bad day, It's not that hard.

Comment: try a GET. (coz you're not really POSTing)

Comment: Also a fail. I will be posting eventually. I'm trying to build my way there. It's a two parameter call that worked just fine when it was its own .aspx page.

Comment: Remove the localhost from the url (see updated answer). What JavaScript errors are you getting?

Comment: Your edit for contentType fixed it...or at least I am getting a `success` alert.

Comment: Good :) Always simplify problems down to the bare minimum and you'll solve them. Now `alert` some of your data.

Comment: Everything is coming up undefined -.- (Thank you for your patience). Though, I could have sworn I had this configuration in there at one point. I would add a piece and save/refresh..try again.

Comment: `alert(data.d);` = {"name":"Please","value":"Work"}
I can't get Please and Work out of it.

Comment: Just changed the `[WebMethod]` to return `DummyString` instead of string. Dropped the serializer (which worked like it should when it was a standalone page), and it seems to be where I thought I should have been about 4 hrs ago. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Service return response in .d parameters  try following

```
msg.d.name
```

Comment: I'm working on @Sam Leach 's method. I've taken the return data out of it. I can't get the call to complete at this point. I read that and tried before with no luck btw.